# How to get an image to appear when someone clicks a checkbox

Tags: jquery

I want a little happy face to float up and disappear after someone clicks a checkbox.  Is there a simple way to do this with jQuery?

Comment: This question is too generic. There are many many ways you can do this and it depends on your html css etc.. What have you tried so far? Can you post you jQuery code?

Answer (score 0):

Yep you can do it by find offset of your check box. Set position of your icon on click event of check box and hide it after delay.

But as  elclanrs said you have to clear how's your layout, html, css and what you did so far

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need exactly. Anyway you can do whatever you want like this.
Suppose you have a checkbox with id = mycheckbox and img with id myimage (image has style="display:none;")

```
jQuery("input[id=mycheckbox]").click(function(){
   jQuery("img[id=myimage]").fadeIn('slow');//if you want animated
   //or simply
   jQuery("img[id=myimage]").show();
});
```

Probably you need to show and hide picture on checkbox click you can do that like this

```
jQuery("input[id=mycheckbox]").click(function(){
   if(jQuery("img[id=myimage]").is(":visible")){
       jQuery("img[id=myimage]").hide();
   }else{
       jQuery("img[id=myimage]").show();
   }
});
```